# Could not load type from assembly in .Net Core 3.0

Tags: c#, .net-3.0

I updated my .net core application's (MVC web app) target framework from v2.2 to v3.0 and it won't start anymore. I updated all nuget packages that are in my app, and removed the ones that were not needed anymore. Now I am getting this error when trying to start the app. There are no build errors.

```
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.FileResultExecutorBase' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=3.1.3.0
```

There are no references to FileResultExecutorBase in this project and when running `dotnet --include-transitive` I didn't find any dependencies to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal. I have tried different things to Startup's ConfigureServices and Configure, but the error stays the same.

These are my packages now, copied from csproj-file:

```
-EPPlus.Core Version "1.5.4"  
-Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect Version "3.0.0"  
-Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore Version "3.0.0"  
-Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson Version "3.0.0"  
-Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices Version "3.0.0"   
-Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug Version "3.0.0"  
-Newtonsoft.Json Version "12.0.3" 
-React.AspNet Version "5.2.4"
```

Also from csproj-file:

```
-TargetFramework: netcoreapp3.0  
-Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"
```

I tried to remove that EPPlus.Core package (it's deprecated) and rebuild without it, but as a result was still the same error.

Comment: "I updated my .net core application's (MVC web app) target framework from v2.2 to v3.0" - sidenote: from one out of support outdated to another out of support outdated ;) 3.0 is already out of support - go straight to 3.1

Comment: I'm on a path from 1.1 to 3.1. @TomTom

Comment: Consider skipping EntityFrameworkCore. After months of trying to get it working, I am now ripping it out - EntityFramework 6 (the one that is "old and outdated tech" - which seems to mean "working") is now usable in netstandard, which includes .NET core.

Comment: Hmm, I’ll look into that! @TomTom

Comment: @toffee20 Could you remove the "Solution" from the question to a new answer and mark it as accepted?

Comment: I've [rolled back](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61523672/revisions) this question to revision 2 (i.e. before you put the answer in the question). Please post the solution as a new answer to your question - and not in the question itself. Also, things like "Solved" should not be added to titles when they have a solution - the presence of an accepted answer (with a green tick next to it) is the way to signal that a question has been answered.

Comment: @toffee20 Great! Welcome to StackOverflow ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happened was that this project had dependency to another project (call it B) within the same solution. Project B has target framework of .NET Standard 1.6. Project B is run with this project and it uses class 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.FileResultExecutorBase'.